# Como escrever duas ReadLine em uma unica linha?

Tags: c#, console

Estava fazendo alguns testes e quando tentei fazer um exemplo de sistema de data, no caso nascimento eu me deparei com o problema, que voce pode apenas escrever no final do Console.Write(), quando voce coloca um Console.ReadLine(), voce pode escrever e definir aquela variavel. Porém só da para fazer isso apenas uma vez, como posso usar isso 3 vezes com 3 variaveis em apenas uma linha? No caso eu queria colocar o dia atrás da primeira barra do nascimento e o mes, na segunda.

Script:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string nome;
        string profissao;
        int idade;
        int dia, mes, ano;

        Console.Write("Nome: "); nome = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("idade: "); idade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Nascimento: / /"); ano = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Profissão: "); profissao = Console.ReadLine();    
    }
}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Voce pode usar Console.SetCursorPosition (x, y)

Comment: Como eu poderia incluir isto no meu script? Porque pelo que vi ele só muda a posição da string;

Comment: Não seria isso aqui que está procurando, `ano = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` .[Documentação da classe `DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a função `Console.SetCursorPosition` você alterar o a posição que o cursor, juntamente com isso, você pode utilizar a função `Console.ReadKey()` para ler apenas um caractere.

Com base nisso, criei um pequeno exemplo de como você poderia realizar tal questão.
Veja:

```
static bool ChecarTamanhoString(string variable, int size)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variable) || variable?.Trim().Length < size;
}

static string LerCampoData(string mensagem)
{
    string dia = "", mes = "", ano = "";

    Console.Write($"{mensagem}:  /  /    ");
    bool valido;
    do
    {
        //Calcula a posição do cursor
        //baseado no que já foi informado pelo usuário
        //Exemplo: (Tamanho da mensagem) + (dias, se houver algo) + (mes, se houver dias informado) + (ano, se houver dias e mês informado)
        int cursorLeftPosition = (mensagem.Length + 1) +
                (dia != null ? dia.Length : 0) +
                (dia?.Length == 2 ? 1 + mes.Length : 0) +
                (mes?.Length == 2 && dia?.Length == 2 ? ano.Length + 1 : 0);

        //Posiciona o cursor conforme o que foi calculado
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeftPosition, Console.CursorTop);
                
        //Lê apenas uma letra do console
        var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                                
        if (ChecarTamanhoString(dia, 2))
            dia += key;
        else if (ChecarTamanhoString(mes, 2))
            mes += key;
        else if (ChecarTamanhoString(ano, 4))
            ano += key;

        //Caso todas as variaveis estiverem informadas, está valido
        valido = (dia.Length + mes.Length + ano.Length) == 8;
    }
    while (!valido);

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop + 1);
    return $"{dia}/{mes}/{ano}";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Início");
    bool dataNascimentoValida;
    do
    {
        string inputDate = LerCampoData("Data de nascimento");
        dataNascimentoValida = DateTime.TryParse(inputDate, out DateTime dataNascimento);
        if (!dataNascimentoValida)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data inválida");
        }
    }
    while (!dataNascimentoValida);

    Console.WriteLine("Fim");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!